# Not able to find General Setting in Sonar

Tags: sonarqube

I am using SonarQube 3.5. I am not able to find Settings > General Settings > General > Differential Views. Please help me to trace above setting

Answer (score 1):

I am able to find that in Sonar General Settings (**I have the Version 3.7.2**).

It is the Default Functionality given into SonarQube Setting.

If you still unable to find the **Settings > General Settings > General > Differential Views**
then you need to Upgrade the Version.

You can download from following link

http://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/

Below is the Link to Screenshot for the Same

http://i1302.photobucket.com/albums/ag129/jugalthakkar/Sonar37_zpsf96b53ff.png

You can see the **Differential Views** in this Screen